# Hamburger button not propely aligned using Material Design Lite

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, material-design-lite

I have this simple code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Always shows a header, even in smaller screens. -->
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
      <header class="mdl-layout__header">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
          <!-- Title -->
          <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
          <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
          <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
          <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
          <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

but the result I get is really not like CodePen or Google website (getmdl.io); the hamburger button is not properly centered. Is there a solution for that?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just discovered the problem, I forgot to add `<!doctype html>`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Always shows a header, even in smaller screens. -->
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
      <header class="mdl-layout__header">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
          <!-- Title -->
          <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
          <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
          <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
          <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
          <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: More information: MDL uses HTML elements and CSS properties that require the HTML5 doctype.
Such a simple header to add, but I forgot it as well, so thanks for posting your answer!

Comment: @LyleBrown thank you so much for the details I didn't really know the reason why it does not work I just compared between codes and found solution